# How to show Toast when Device wi-Fi is turned On using BroadCastreceiver and Service?

Tags: android

I want to make application that **should not extends any Activity class**.

My Application must run in background and show Toast when I touch my device Wi-Fi turned on. My code for NetworkUtil is here

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    } 
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
```

}

**And receiver class is here. PLease help me to show Toast.**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

**And My Manifest is **

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.viralpatel.network"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name="net.viralpatel.network.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you added 
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter> in the receivers tag in manifest?

Comment: Still the toast ins't visible? Did you check if the receiver is getting called?Add Log.d("someTag","Receiver called"); in onReceive method Now change the wifi and check logcat if the receiver is getting called

Comment: NO sir Receiver is not Called,, I put Log.i() but there is no any message is displaying into LogCat

Comment: So this is the issue. Not the toast. Post your manifest.

Comment: Sir same I am using here.. U can see,

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

Comment: Please sir help me.. I am trying by last day but still M an not getting output

Comment: @crashOveride Sir, I update my question. Now You can see manifest.. also in comment the URL is there which I am following.. I want same  output

Comment: Is your receiver java file in following directory structure ->
net->viralpatel->network->NetworkChangeReceiver.java

Comment: yes sir.. In a package. there are two .java file.. One extends Broadcast Receiver and another is NeyworlUtl

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

Comment: @crashOveride did you find any soultion sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android 3.1 and higher, the user must launch one of your activities before any manifest-registered BroadcastReceiver will work.

See the Android 3.1 release notes, specifically the "Launch controls on stopped applications" section.
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html
Make a sample activity and try. Will work.

Without activity it won't work.

Comment: Thank you Sir but still there is any way to achieve this any how ?